# What effect did DataFrame.loc() cause on the data frame?

Tags: python, numpy

I used numpy.random.permutation() to generate random order to an original data frame X and want to assign whole X to X_perm by the random order.

```
X_perm=X
y_perm=y
perm = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
for i in range(len(perm)):
  X_perm.loc[i]=(X.loc[perm[i]])
  y_perm.loc[i]=(y.loc[perm[i]])
```

Just found that after running the code, the first record of X given by X[0:1] changed comparing to the case before running.

Strange. I didn't make any operation on X but assign its values to a new data frame. How did it cause the alteration of X value?
Cheers

Comment: Instead of `X_perm=X`, replace it with `X_perm=X.copy()`. When you use `=`, you're copying by reference and therefore any changes made to either `X` or `X_perm` will affect the other.

Comment: `X_perm=X` does not create a copy. It just binds the name X_perm to the same object referenced by X. If you then mutate the object referenced by X_perm, you mutate the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this unexpected behavior is that X_perm is not an array that is independent of X. X_perm is a reference to X. So modifications to X_perm are also modifications made to X.

To demonstrate this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(16)
print a
b = a  # as your X_perm = X
print b  # same as print a above
b[0] = -999
print a  # has been modified
print b  # has been modified

a[-1] = -999
print a  # has been modified
print b  # has been modified

# using copy
a = np.arange(16)
print a
b = a.copy()  # b is separate reference to array
print b  # same as print a above
b[0] = -999
print a  # has NOT been modified
print b  # has been modified

a[-1] = -999
print a  # has been modified
print b  # has NOT been modified
```

To do what you want, you need to X_perm to be a copy of X.

```
X_perm = X.copy()
```

See also [this relevant numpy doc on copy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html)